# MainActivity should load during Splash Screen

Tags: java, android, splash-screen

I am new to Android and I have an Android App, on which i have added a "Splash Screen" and After that, the MainActivity gets loaded. but the MainActivity takes additional 5-6 seconds to load.
Would it be possible that the contents of MainActivity gets loaded in splash Screen and when Splash Screen ends it should display MainActivity without taking additional 5-6 seconds.

Please help me out, i have added the code of my MainActivity as well as Splash Screen. It will be your most kindness in my favour that if you edit my code and give me the perfect code.

Thanks in Advance.

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MenuItemCallback, ConfigParser.CallBack
{

    private static final int PERMISSION_REQUESTCODE = 123;

    //Layout
    public Toolbar mToolbar;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private DisableableViewPager viewPager;
    private NavigationView navigationView;
    public DrawerLayout drawer;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle;

    //Adapters
    private TabAdapter adapter;
    private static SimpleMenu menu;

    //Keep track of the interstitials we show
    private int interstitialCount = -1;
    private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;

    //Data to pass to a fragment
    public static String FRAGMENT_DATA = "transaction_data";
    public static String FRAGMENT_CLASS = "transation_target";

    //Permissions Queu
    List<NavItem> queueItem;
    int queueMenuItemId;

    //InstanceState (rotation)
    private Bundle savedInstanceState;
    private static final String STATE_MENU_INDEX = "MENUITEMINDEX";
    private static final String STATE_PAGER_INDEX = "VIEWPAGERPOSITION";
    private static final String STATE_ACTIONS = "ACTIONS";


    @Override
    public void configLoaded( boolean facedException )
    {
        if ( facedException || menu.getFirstMenuItem() == null ) {
            if ( Helper.isOnlineShowDialog( MainActivity.this ) )
                Toast.makeText( this, R.string.invalid_configuration, Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
        } else {
            if ( savedInstanceState == null ) {
                menuItemClicked( menu.getFirstMenuItem(), 0, false );
            } else {
                ArrayList<NavItem> actions = (ArrayList<NavItem>) savedInstanceState.getSerializable( STATE_ACTIONS );
                int menuItemId = savedInstanceState.getInt( STATE_MENU_INDEX );
                int viewPagerPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt( STATE_PAGER_INDEX );

                menuItemClicked( actions, menuItemId, false );
                viewPager.setCurrentItem( viewPagerPosition );
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState )
    {
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );

        this.savedInstanceState = savedInstanceState;

        //Load the appropriate layout
        if ( useTabletMenu() ) {
            setContentView( R.layout.activity_main_tablet );
            Helper.setStatusBarColor( MainActivity.this,
                                      ContextCompat.getColor( this, R.color.myPrimaryDarkColor ) );
        } else {
            setContentView( R.layout.activity_main );
        }

        mToolbar = findViewById( R.id.toolbar );
        setSupportActionBar( mToolbar );

        if ( !useTabletMenu() )
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled( true );
        else {
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled( false );
        }

        if ( Config.HIDE_TOOLBAR ) {
            getSupportActionBar().hide();
        }

        //Drawer
        if ( !useTabletMenu() ) {
            drawer = findViewById( R.id.drawer );
            toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                    this, drawer, mToolbar, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close );
            drawer.setDrawerListener( toggle );
            toggle.syncState();
        }

        //Layouts
        tabLayout = findViewById( R.id.tabs );
        viewPager = findViewById( R.id.viewpager );

        //Check if we should open a fragment based on the arguments we have
        if ( getIntent().getExtras() != null && getIntent().getExtras().containsKey( FRAGMENT_CLASS ) ) {
            try {
                Class<? extends Fragment> fragmentClass = (Class<? extends Fragment>) getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable( FRAGMENT_CLASS );
                if ( fragmentClass != null ) {
                    String[] extra = getIntent().getExtras().getStringArray( FRAGMENT_DATA );

                    HolderActivity.startActivity( this, fragmentClass, extra );
                    finish();
                    //Optionally, we can also point intents to holderactivity directly instead of MainAc.
                }
            } catch ( Exception e ) {
                //If we come across any errors, just continue and open the default fragment
                Log.printStackTrace( e );
            }
        }

        //Menu items
        navigationView = findViewById( R.id.nav_view );

        menu = new SimpleMenu( navigationView.getMenu(), this );
        if ( Config.USE_HARDCODED_CONFIG ) {
            Config.configureMenu( menu, this );
        } else if ( !Config.CONFIG_URL.isEmpty() && Config.CONFIG_URL.contains( "http" ) )
            new ConfigParser( Config.CONFIG_URL, menu, this, this ).execute();
        else
            new ConfigParser( "config.json", menu, this, this ).execute();

        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager( viewPager );

        if ( !useTabletMenu() ) {
            drawer.setStatusBarBackgroundColor(
                    ContextCompat.getColor( this, R.color.myPrimaryDarkColor ) );
        }

        applyDrawerLocks();

        //Ads
        Helper.admobLoader( this, findViewById( R.id.adView ) );
        if ( getResources().getString( R.string.admob_interstitial_id ).length() > 0
                && Config.INTERSTITIAL_INTERVAL > 0
                && !SettingsFragment.getIsPurchased( this ) ) {
            mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd( this );
            mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId( getResources().getString( R.string.admob_interstitial_id ) );
            AdRequest adRequestInter = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice( AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR ).build();
            mInterstitialAd.loadAd( adRequestInter );

            mInterstitialAd.setAdListener( new AdListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onAdClosed()
                {
                    // Load the next interstitial.
                    mInterstitialAd.loadAd( new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice( AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR ).build() );
                }

            } );
        }

        Helper.updateAndroidSecurityProvider( this );

        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener( new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener()
        {
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged( int state )
            {
            }

            public void onPageScrolled( int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels )
            {
            }

            public void onPageSelected( int position )
            {
                onTabBecomesActive( position );
            }
        } );

    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult( int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults )
    {
        switch ( requestCode ) {
            case PERMISSION_REQUESTCODE:
                boolean allGranted = true;
                for ( int grantResult : grantResults ) {
                    if ( grantResult != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ) {
                        allGranted = false;
                    }
                }
                if ( allGranted ) {
                    //Retry to open the menu item
                    menuItemClicked( queueItem, queueMenuItemId, false );
                } else {
                    // Permission Denied
                    Toast.makeText( MainActivity.this, getResources().getString( R.string.permissions_required ), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT )
                            .show();
                }
                break;
            default:
                super.onRequestPermissionsResult( requestCode, permissions, grantResults );
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void menuItemClicked( List<NavItem> actions, int menuItemIndex, boolean requiresPurchase )
    {
        // Checking the drawer should be open on start
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences( getBaseContext() );
        boolean openOnStart = Config.DRAWER_OPEN_START || prefs.getBoolean( "menuOpenOnStart", false );
        if ( drawer != null ) {
            boolean firstClick = ( savedInstanceState == null && adapter == null );
            if ( openOnStart && !useTabletMenu() && firstClick ) {
                drawer.openDrawer( GravityCompat.START );
            } else {
                //Close the drawer
                drawer.closeDrawer( GravityCompat.START );
            }
        }

        //Check if the user is allowed to open item
        if ( requiresPurchase && !isPurchased() ) return; //isPurchased will handle this.
        if ( !checkPermissionsHandleIfNeeded( actions, menuItemIndex ) )
            return; //checkPermissions will handle.

        if ( isCustomIntent( actions ) ) return;

        //Uncheck all other items, check the current item
        for ( MenuItem menuItem : menu.getMenuItems() ) {
            if ( menuItem.getItemId() == menuItemIndex ) {
                menuItem.setChecked( true );
            } else
                menuItem.setChecked( false );
        }

        //Load the new tab
        adapter = new TabAdapter( getSupportFragmentManager(), actions, this );
        viewPager.setAdapter( adapter );

        //Show or hide the tab bar depending on if we need it
        if ( actions.size() == 1 ) {
            tabLayout.setVisibility( View.GONE );
            viewPager.setPagingEnabled( false );
        } else {
            tabLayout.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
            viewPager.setPagingEnabled( true );
        }
        ( (CustomAppBarLayout) mToolbar.getParent() ).setExpanded( true, true );

        //Show in interstitial
        showInterstitial();

        onTabBecomesActive( 0 );
    }

    private void onTabBecomesActive( int position )
    {
        Fragment fragment = adapter.getItem( position );
        //If fragment does not support collapse, or if OS does not support collapse, disable collapsing toolbar
        if ( ( fragment instanceof CollapseControllingFragment
                && !( (CollapseControllingFragment) fragment ).supportsCollapse() )
                ||
                ( android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT ) )
            lockAppBar();
        else
            unlockAppBar();

        if ( position != 0 )
            showInterstitial();
    }

    /**
     * Show an interstitial ad
     */
    public void showInterstitial()
    {
        if ( interstitialCount == ( Config.INTERSTITIAL_INTERVAL - 1 ) ) {
            if ( mInterstitialAd != null && mInterstitialAd.isLoaded() ) {
                mInterstitialAd.show();
            }

            interstitialCount = 0;
        } else {
            interstitialCount++;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Checks if the item is/contains a custom intent, and if that the case it will handle it.
     *
     * @param items List of NavigationItems
     * @return True if the item is a custom intent, in that case
     */
    private boolean isCustomIntent( List<NavItem> items )
    {
        NavItem customIntentItem = null;
        for ( NavItem item : items ) {
            if ( CustomIntent.class.isAssignableFrom( item.getFragment() ) ) {
                customIntentItem = item;
            }
        }

        if ( customIntentItem == null ) return false;
        if ( items.size() > 1 )
            Log.e( "INFO", "Custom Intent Item must be only child of menu item! Ignorning all other tabs" );

        CustomIntent.performIntent( MainActivity.this, customIntentItem.getData() );
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * If the item can be opened because it either has been purchased or does not require a purchase to show.
     *
     * @return true if the app is purchased. False if the app hasn't been purchased, or if iaps are disabled
     */
    private boolean isPurchased()
    {
        String license = getResources().getString( R.string.google_play_license );
        // if item does not require purchase, or app has purchased, or license is null/empty (app has no in app purchases)
        if ( !SettingsFragment.getIsPurchased( this ) && !license.equals( "" ) ) {
            String[] extra = new String[]{ SettingsFragment.SHOW_DIALOG };
            HolderActivity.startActivity( this, SettingsFragment.class, extra );

            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Checks if the item can be opened because it has sufficient permissions.
     *
     * @param tabs The tabs to check
     * @return true if the item is safe to open
     */
    private boolean checkPermissionsHandleIfNeeded( List<NavItem> tabs, int menuItemId )
    {
        if ( android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M ) return true;

        List<String> allPermissions = new ArrayList<>();
        for ( NavItem tab : tabs ) {
            if ( PermissionsFragment.class.isAssignableFrom( tab.getFragment() ) ) {
                try {
                    for ( String permission : ( (PermissionsFragment) tab.getFragment().newInstance() ).requiredPermissions() ) {
                        if ( !allPermissions.contains( permission ) )
                            allPermissions.add( permission );
                    }
                } catch ( Exception e ) {
                    //Don't really care
                }
            }
        }

        if ( allPermissions.size() > 1 ) {
            boolean allGranted = true;
            for ( String permission : allPermissions ) {
                if ( checkSelfPermission( permission ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED )
                    allGranted = false;
            }

            if ( !allGranted ) {
                requestPermissions( allPermissions.toArray( new String[ 0 ] ), PERMISSION_REQUESTCODE );
                queueItem = tabs;
                queueMenuItemId = menuItemId;
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu( Menu menu )
    {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate( R.menu.settings_menu, menu );
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected( MenuItem item )
    {
        // Handle item selection
        switch ( item.getItemId() ) {
            case R.id.settings:
                HolderActivity.startActivity( this, SettingsFragment.class, null );
                return true;
            case R.id.favorites:
                HolderActivity.startActivity( this, FavFragment.class, null );
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected( item );
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        Fragment activeFragment = null;
        if ( adapter != null )
            activeFragment = adapter.getCurrentFragment();

        if ( drawer != null && drawer.isDrawerOpen( GravityCompat.START ) ) {
            drawer.closeDrawer( GravityCompat.START );
        } else if ( activeFragment instanceof BackPressFragment ) {
            boolean handled = ( (BackPressFragment) activeFragment ).handleBackPress();
            if ( !handled ) {
                super.onBackPressed();
            }
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult( int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data )
    {
        super.onActivityResult( requestCode, resultCode, data );
        List<Fragment> fragments = getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments();
        if ( fragments != null )
            for ( Fragment frag : fragments )
                if ( frag != null )
                    frag.onActivityResult( requestCode, resultCode, data );
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged( Configuration newConfig )
    {
        super.onConfigurationChanged( newConfig );
        if ( adapter != null && !( adapter.getCurrentFragment() instanceof ConfigurationChangeFragment ) ) {
            this.recreate();
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState( Bundle outState )
    {
        super.onSaveInstanceState( outState );

        if ( adapter == null ) return;

        int menuItemIndex = 0;
        for ( MenuItem menuItem : menu.getMenuItems() ) {
            if ( menuItem.isChecked() ) {
                menuItemIndex = menuItem.getItemId();
                break;
            }
        }

        outState.putSerializable( STATE_ACTIONS, ( (ArrayList<NavItem>) adapter.getActions() ) );
        outState.putInt( STATE_MENU_INDEX, menuItemIndex );
        outState.putInt( STATE_PAGER_INDEX, viewPager.getCurrentItem() );
    }

    //Check if we should adjust our layouts for tablets
    public boolean useTabletMenu()
    {
        return ( getResources().getBoolean( R.bool.isWideTablet ) && Config.TABLET_LAYOUT );
    }

    //Apply the appropiate locks to the drawer
    public void applyDrawerLocks()
    {
        if ( drawer == null ) {
            if ( Config.HIDE_DRAWER )
                navigationView.setVisibility( View.GONE );
            return;
        }

        if ( Config.HIDE_DRAWER ) {
            toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled( false );
            drawer.setDrawerLockMode( DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED );
        } else {
            drawer.setDrawerLockMode( DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED );
        }
    }

    private void lockAppBar()
    {
        AppBarLayout.LayoutParams params =
                (AppBarLayout.LayoutParams) mToolbar.getLayoutParams();
        params.setScrollFlags( 0 );
    }

    private void unlockAppBar()
    {
        AppBarLayout.LayoutParams params =
                (AppBarLayout.LayoutParams) mToolbar.getLayoutParams();
        params.setScrollFlags( AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.SCROLL_FLAG_SCROLL
                                       | AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.SCROLL_FLAG_ENTER_ALWAYS );
    }

}
```

**SplashScreen**

```
public class SplashScreen extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
use this code inside the splashActivity


public class SplashScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

    private  static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT=5000;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                SplashScreen.this.startActivity(new Intent(SplashScreen.this,MainActivity.class));
                SplashScreen.this.finish();
                finish();

            }
        },SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
    }
}
```

Comment: sir but with this we are only delaying the splasScreen, My Question is that I want MainActivitie's data to be fetched in Splash and splash should only finish when data of main activity is compleated

Answer (score 0):

It's probably the loading of the ads that is delaying the activity from starting.
Try commenting out the loading of the ads in your MainActivity onCreate and see if it loads faster. Video ads might take a while to load.

If so, try doing an async load of the ads a couple of seconds after the Activity has been created like this:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
     // load your ads here
  }
}, 2000);
```

Comment: In Strings i am not giving value to Ad Code, so ads are not loading at att but my app still takes 4-6 seconds to load after splash, i want splash should remain till the data of mainActivity is fetched or compleated.